# Include data files when publishing a WPF App

Tags: wpf, deployment, path, publish

i want to publish a WPF app with ClickOnce, but i'd like to include data files that are in my project (json and txt). 
Actually, the app works when building from visual, but crash when i publish it with ClickOnce, because it can't find these data files after publishing. 
How can i specify somewhere, to deploy the app with those data files? Or should i change the path of those files in the code?

Hope my problem is clear, thanks.

Comment: You should copy your files to output directory, I guess

Comment: What do you mean output directory?

Comment: Your app output directory. Set `copy always` or `copy if newer` in data files properties in your project

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Sorry but i dont understand what i have to do, could you please be a little more specific?